# String not being appended in function

Tags: javascript

I am trying to parse a JSON and build a HTML string to append to the DOM but no matter what I do the string is only returning the first element in the JSON.

Here's the js:

```
var menu_json = {
    "name": "Personal Banking",
    "url": "/test1.html",
    "children": [
      {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "test2",
        "url": "/products/deposits/test2.html",
        "children": [
          {
            "id": "1",
            "name": "test3",
            "url": "/products/deposits/test3.html",
            "children": [
              {
                "id": "1",
                "name": "test5",
                "url": "test5"
              },
              {
                "id": "2",
                "name": "test6",
                "url": "/products/deposits/test6.html"
              },
              {
                "id": "3",
                "name": "test7",
                "url": "/products/deposits/test7.html"

              },
              {
                "id": "4",
                "name": "test8",
                "url": "/products/deposits/test8.html"
              },
              {
                "id": "5",
                "name": "test9",
                "url": "/products/deposits/test9.html"
              },
              {
                "id": "6",
                "name": "test10",
                "url": "/products/deposits/test10.html"
              },
              {
                "id": "7",
                "name": "test11",
                "url": "/products/deposits/test11.html"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
}

var test_html = "<ul>",
buildNavHelper = function(curNode){
    test_html += "<li>" + curNode.name;
    if (curNode.hasOwnProperty('children')){
       test_html += "<ul>" + _.map(curNode.children, buildNavHelper) + "</ul>";
    }
    test_html += "</li>";   
};

buildNavHelper(menu_json);
test_html += "</ul>";

$('#thing').append(test_html);
```

Heres a fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/w734bvw7/

Comment: You don't have JSON. You have a JS object, and it's already parsed.

Comment: I think you would benefit more from underscore's or lodash's [`_.template`](https://lodash.com/docs#template) functionality than trying to build HTML by mapping over this object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`buildNavHelper()` has no return statement, so there's nothing coming back from `_.map()`. The outer test_html isn't in scope. Try this:

```
buildNavHelper = function(curNode){
    var test_html = "<li>" + curNode.name;
    if (curNode.hasOwnProperty('children')){
       test_html += "<ul>" + _.map(curNode.children, buildNavHelper).join("") + "</ul>";
    }
    test_html += "</li>";  
    return test_html;
};

test_html = "<ul>" + buildNavHelper(menu_json) + "</ul>";
```

Note the addition of `.join()` to avoid having commas in your output.

Also, there's no need to use underscore here; `Array.map()` is native Javascript.

```
buildNavHelper = function(curNode){
    var test_html = "<li>" + curNode.name;
    if (curNode.hasOwnProperty('children')){
       test_html += "<ul>" + curNode.children.map(buildNavHelper).join("") + "</ul>";
    }
    test_html += "</li>";  
    return test_html;
};
```

Comment: Glad you included the explanation there.

Comment: I used Lodash (Underscore) for IE8 support

Answer (score 1):

https://jsfiddle.net/w734bvw7/3/

```
buildNavHelper = function(curNode){
    var test_html = "<ul>";
    test_html += "<li>" + curNode.name;
    if (curNode.hasOwnProperty('children')){
        test_html += "<ul>" + _.map(curNode.children, buildNavHelper) + "</ul>";
    }
    test_html += "</li>";   
    test_html += "</ul>";
    return test_html;    
};

$('#thing').append(buildNavHelper(menu_json));
```

Answer (score 1):

Building the list using HTML strings can produce HTML injection. I recommend DOM methods instead:

```js
function buildNavHelper(arr) {
  var ul = document.createElement('ul');
  for(var i=0; i<arr.length; ++i) {
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(arr[i].name));
    if(arr[i].children)
      li.appendChild(buildNavHelper(arr[i].children));
    ul.appendChild(li);
  }
  return ul;
}
```

```js
var menu_json = {
  "name": "Personal Banking",
  "url": "/test1.html",
  "children": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "test2",
      "url": "/products/deposits/test2.html",
      "children": [
        {
          "id": "1",
          "name": "test3",
          "url": "/products/deposits/test3.html",
          "children": [
            {
              "id": "1",
              "name": "test5",
              "url": "test5"
            },
            {
              "id": "2",
              "name": "test6",
              "url": "/products/deposits/test6.html"
            },
            {
              "id": "3",
              "name": "test7",
              "url": "/products/deposits/test7.html"

            },
            {
              "id": "4",
              "name": "test8",
              "url": "/products/deposits/test8.html"
            },
            {
              "id": "5",
              "name": "test9",
              "url": "/products/deposits/test9.html"
            },
            {
              "id": "6",
              "name": "test10",
              "url": "/products/deposits/test10.html"
            },
            {
              "id": "7",
              "name": "test11",
              "url": "/products/deposits/test11.html"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

function buildNavHelper(arr) {
  var ul = document.createElement('ul');
  for(var i=0; i<arr.length; ++i) {
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(arr[i].name));
    if(arr[i].children)
      li.appendChild(buildNavHelper(arr[i].children));
    ul.appendChild(li);
  }
  return ul;
}
document.querySelector('#thing').appendChild(buildNavHelper([menu_json]));
```

```html
<div id="thing"></div>
```